# How do I make my custom android IME show up in the IME menu?

Tags: android

I wrote a simple test IME for android and installed it on the device. I confirmed that the service is on the device by browsing the list of installed services. However, the service is not showing up in the list of keyboards available in the language & input menu. I'm using Android 3.2 on a Asus TF101.

Here's my service declaration

```
<service 
    android:name="keyboard" 
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: I've been looking at the LatinIME samples and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone know how to get the soft keyboard to show up in settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android SDK have softkeyboard example.
And may be this link help you [Creating an Input Method](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-input-method.html)